# What might allow a kaiju to exist in real life?

Tags: science-based, hard-science, xenobiology

Assuming we prescribe to the theory that kaiju are not the result of years of evolution or sudden, drastic mutation but rather purposefully designed and created weapons of war, how could they be built to circumvent the many physical problems surrounding their being? Hyper-efficient metabolisms and circulatory systems? Bones made from advanced metamaterials like graphene or carbon nanotubes? Bodies that are larger at the base to disperse weight?

Comment: 1) What's a kaiju? Don't assume that everyone knows what a Kaiju is, and put some more information in your question. 2) I count way too many question marks in this question, making this too broad. 3) Short answer to your question is "it's not possible."

Comment: @Aify Note that while there are several question marks, they are all related to the common concept of the question as a whole; they're kind of a focus for answerers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to convincingly explain Kaiju](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/52174/6986). Note, however, that this question asks for hard-science and that one is science-based.

Comment: I suggest removing the hard-science tag as that will make your question more likely to be answered.

Comment: @Frostfyre It may be a similar question, but this one focuses on what is required to make a Kaiju feasible. As the only person who answered the other question, I can see this question has a better focus on the problems to be circumvented for a plausible Kaiju.

Comment: How to build Godzilla: first build a scale model of a city, put an actor in a foam rubber suit, shoot footage, then tell everyone it's out in the ocean sleeping right now so don't pollute the water.